# How to express a half of an axis?

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

In my paper, a half-line extending from coordinates (x,y) at an angle of Theta to the x-axis is called an HL; and an axis containing this HL is called a T-axis.

Hence, the HL is the same as the half of the T-axis with nonnegative t, as shown in the below figure.

[image]

I want to express formally the relationship between the T-axis and the HL.

> The HL is the T-axis where t >= 0.

> The HL is the T-axis with t >= 0.

> The HL is the T-axis for t >= 0.

Which one is correct?
All of them are wrong?
If so, can you give me the correct sentence?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks as if you mean the t-line with x>=0, not t>=0. The coordinate system you show seems to be in x,y; each point on T should have an x- and a y-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical grammar is probably a little different than standard English, but out of the three you've listed "where" is probably the best adverb to use for this statement (although "for" is pretty similar in meaning). That said, I'd propose "when" as an alternative that could be considered slightly clearer and more natural as the value of t is not always >= 0.

Answer (score 1):

That is the "positive *T*-axis" (or, if it is significant the "non-negative T-axis".

This usage can be seen more often when talking about the orthoganal axis "[consider the region bounded by the positive y-axis, the line x=8 ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901170/consider-the-region-bounded-by-the-positive-y-axis)" But it can be used with any cartesian basis.

> The half line is the positive *T*-axis.